# Adding graphic to graphicsLayer on top of feature layer using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have multiple featureLayers and one graphicLayer for adding graphics. However I cannot add a graphic to this layer. Can someone help with what I'm doing wrong ?

```
featureLayer.on("click", function (evt) {
  attrs = evt.graphic.attributes;
  if(clickmode == 1) {
    var highlightSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0]));
    var location = new Point(evt.mapPoint.x, evt.mapPoint.y, evt.spatialReference);
    graphicLayer.add(new Graphic(location, highlightSymbol));
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is clickmode being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you've created an empty symbol. you should try specify a [shape](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/simplemarkersymbol-amd.html#constants) and size. i would suggest you use the AMD module require "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol" :

```
var highlightSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 10, '', new Color([255, 0, 0]));
```

also, *maybe* you could even make a new graphic, without cerating a new Point, just by using evt.mapPoint, which is already a Point :

```
graphicLayer.add(new Graphic(evt.mapPoint, highlightSymbol));
```